After rejecting CCTS's Investigation Findings, which's your next action against a telecommunications service provider?
Which beneath is correct?  Small claims court ? Or judicial review ("JR") ?

You can sue the service provider in Small Claims Court. You can do this without complaining to  the Commission for Complaints for Telecom-television Services (CCTS). You can also sue if you reject a CCTS decision.

I quote Commission for Complaints for Telecom-television Services  (CCTS).

If you reject the Investigation Findings, your provider is not required to carry out any remedies. You would retain all the usual rights and remedies, and you are free to pursue them.

But our moderator, Dale M, wrote

In this case, the CRT declined to act, that almost certainly opens the door for judicial review.


Customers would sue the service provider in Small Claims Court.
CCTS is a non-governmental mediator, not an administrative tribunal.
